# My server is not receiving any php uploaded files

Tags: php, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, port-forwarding

I have a local LAN server running on a Raspberry Pi (apache2) with PHP installed. I know that PHP is working, because I wrote a test file, `echo "Hello, World!"` and it worked. But, whenever I upload a file on the same router to the server through a PHP script, it doesn't work. If I try to upload a file on the Raspberry Pi itself, it works fine.

F.Y.I, I'm trying to do this so I can then print the uploaded file (which is working fine on local files on the Raspberry Pi). Is this an issue with port forwarding or something? I am new to this whole area of computing (I am mainly a software developer). If it is a port forwarding problem, my router/modem is the Virgin Media Super Hub. In the apache2 server error log, it says that `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` is not a file ("file" is the input name). For some reason, this happens as well on all the machines I've tested it on. But no problems on a file on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Are you sure it is Raspberry Pi specific? Does it work on your localhost or test server?

Comment: I am using the Raspberry Pi. And no, I can't connect to the server through "localhost", I can only connect through the local ip address of the raspberry pi

Comment: what phpinfo() says?

Comment: I have a feeling this is a permissions thing. When you upload through the PHP script, the user running as your webserver [usually nouser or www-data] versus uploading it as user "pi" -- Please do an "ls -la" on that upload directory and let's compare the permissions for files uploaded using the two different methods.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify in your form the encryption type that it is multipart using

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="whatever.php" method="post"></form>
```

and F.Y.I you would need to **move_uploaded_file** if you wish to re-use the same file later.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to not specify, but I looked at the w3schools site, and I am using the right encryption type. As I said, it is working for local files being "uploaded" from the raspberry pi to the raspberry pi